# Remote validation method in razor pages never gets hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Building from here
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation

I've set up remote validation to a page method:

```
<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="MobileTel" class="form-label">Cellphone Number</label><br />
    <input asp-for="MobileTel" type="tel" class="mobileNumber form-control" required /><br />
    <span asp-validation-for="MobileTel" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

With my PageModel looking like this:

```
[PageRemote(HttpMethod = "post", PageHandlder = "CheckUser", AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken")]
public string MobileTel { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCheckUser()
{
    // Determine if a user exists with the given mobile number.
    var exists = await userManager.FindByMobileTel(MobileTel)

    return new JsonResult(exists);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    try
    {
        if (PageModel.IsValid)
        {
            // Validation passed, do the thing.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log and handle errors.
    }
}
```

At no point do I ever see the `OnPostCheckUser` method getting hit. So where does the validation happen?

As it currently stands, the `OnPost` method gets hit every time as you'd expect but `ModelState.IsValid` is always false (even if I've tried a mobile number corresponding to a user record.

Have I misunderstood a concept or missed a trick here?

How do I correct my code so that remote validation works?

Comment: given your response to Mike's answer.. `PageHandlder` is a typo in the question snippet, right?

Comment: @BrettCaswell a problem with copying code. I can assure you, it's correct in my code file. That would have been trivial to correct otherwise by dint of the ugly red line that would render under `PageHandlder`

Comment: indeed.. but what about the `BindPropertyAttribute` was that just missed in copy paste?

Comment: you also don't have an argument for the property in `OnPostCheckUser()`... should be `OnPostCheckUser(string mobileTel)`.. I don't see anything in that reference material that suggests these function scopes can access instance data, but that seems where your implementation differs, right?

Comment: can you provide confirmation on whether or not a request is made (using WebTools or Fiddler)?

Comment: I've got `[BindProperties]` on the class so I don't have to worry about which ones I'm not binding. Other than that, I'm using WebTools

Comment: in that case, your issue seems like it could be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494904/asp-razor-pages-bindproperties-values-lost-on-post question.  and can be resolved similarly.. you should use `@Model.<Property>` in your razor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had not correctly implemented unobtrusive etc. now I've done that, it does hit the validation method

Comment: hmm.. or perhaps not.. if that helper comment in the answer is actually a solution with BindProperties of the class usage.

Comment: oh.. sorry... I thought you verified the request was being made when referencing to using webtools.. well good.. glad you were able to find a solution.. thought it was going  the route of being something decorative with transpiling consideration